# Connecting classic asp to mysql on iis8

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic

I am getting this error when attempting to connect to mysql using classic asp...
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
I've tried many different things and I think the problem is that I am using IIS 8.

Here is how I am trying to connect to mysql:

```
    Dim oConn, oRs
    Dim qry, connectstr
    Dim db_name, db_username, db_userpassword
    Dim db_server

     db_server = "server"
    db_name = "database"
    db_username = "uid"
    db_userpassword = "pwd"

    connectstr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=" & db_server & ";DATABASE=" & db_name & ";UID=" & db_username & ";PWD=" & db_userpassword
    Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConn.Open connectstr

    response.write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Connected!');</script>")
```

I also tried with the newer odbc 5.1 driver, but had no luck connecting. Any ideas as to what I should try?

Comment: Solved the issue, for future help...
in IIS go to asp settings and enable parent paths.

Answer (score 0):

IF you use 32 bit odbc driver then you permission on iis for 32 Bit Apps : Allowed 
and use this ;

```
 Connection_DSN= "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER="&mysql_server&"; UID="&mysql_user&";pwd="&mysql_pass&";db="&mysql_db&"; stmt=SET NAMES 'latin5';"

    Set con= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    con.Open Connection_DSN
```